# Stopwatch stops upon cell edit/change

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with a stopwatch. Whenever a cell is edited on the same sheet/workbook or a separate Excel file the stopwatch stops.

I know that the issue is related to the fact that when you open a cell for editing all macros suspend.

Is there a workaround which can be used in my particular case?

NOTE: I need to obtain the time elapsed as a value so that it can be used in another function of the file.

```
    Public StopIt As Boolean
    Public ResetIt As Boolean
    Public LastTime

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim StartTime, FinishTime, TotalTime, PauseTime
    StopIt = False
    ResetIt = False
    If Range("F5") = 0 Then
      StartTime = Timer
      PauseTime = 0
      LastTime = 0
    Else
      StartTime = 0
      PauseTime = Timer
    End If
    StartIt:
      DoEvents
      If StopIt = True Then
        LastTime = TotalTime
        Exit Sub
      Else
        FinishTime = Timer
        TotalTime = FinishTime - StartTime + LastTime - PauseTime
        TTime = TotalTime * 100
        HM = TTime Mod 100
        TTime = TTime \ 100
        hh = TTime \ 3600
        TTime = TTime Mod 3600
        MM = TTime \ 60
        SS = TTime Mod 60
        Range("F5").Value = Format(hh, "00") & ":" & Format(MM, "00") & ":" & Format(SS, "00") & "." & Format(HM, "00")
        If ResetIt = True Then
          Range("F5") = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
          LastTime = 0
          PauseTime = 0
          End
        End If
        GoTo StartIt
      End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    StopIt = True
    End Sub


    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
      Range("F5").Value = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
      LastTime = 0
      ResetIt = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just read the time? That clock never stops

Comment: What do you mean by reading the time? The stopwatch is used to time the time you spent on a break. When you start your break you start the stopwatch and when you come back and click on "Stop" it moves the time elapsed into a calculator which tells you how much time you have left from the overall break. The problem is that some people don't leave the desk when they go on a break and tend to just chill at their desks and if they decide to either work on another excel file or enter data in another Sheet of the same file the stopwatch stops and the time spent on a break won't be captured.

Comment: What if you do not start the stopwatch? Human actions can be unexpected

Comment: If you think reading the time will be a viable solution for the problem I am having can you please elaborate how I can implement it and clarify what exactly you mean by that? :) 

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: There is no viable solution. You are dealing with humans, not robots.

Comment: Well, the problem is that it stops after it was started. Pretty much if the user hasn't started the stopwatch before going on a break then he is the one to blame. The important thing is that once started the stopwatch shouldn't stop no matter what until the "Stop" button is pressed.

Best Regards,

Comment: then he is the one to blame ....
Grow up! People are humans, not robots

Comment: The issue is not with what the user does, but with what the macro doesn't. The issue is that the stopwatch stops when a cell is changed in excel. If the user doesn't start the stopwatch then it's their own fault. However, if the user starts the stopwatch and decided either on purpose working on an excel file or by mistake selecting a cell the stopwatch stops counting. This is the issue i am trying to fix.

Comment: You blame too much. Take responibillity of your own code. Fix it! Quit crying!

Comment: Is there a workaround which will prevent the macro from stopping upon randomly entering data in excel. Is it possible to let's say make a bool check if the worksheet has been changed and if so then continue executing the macro?

Comment: Dude..... wth?!?

I am writing here in order to find a possible workaround for the fact that my stopwatch stops upon entering or changing a cell. How and where and who am I blaming ?

Comment: Also the reason for me to post here in the first place is to find people that might have a solution for the problem. What does fix your code quit crying mean?

Comment: Where does this misunderstanding come from?

Comment: Although your macro may not be running while the user is editing, etc, `Timer` continues to be updated by the system and therefore subtracting the value of `Timer` when they start their break from the value of `Timer` when they stop their break will still give the total amount of time of the break.  The only thing you can't do is update the **display** of elapsed time while the break is happening.  (If you want to do that, use an `Application.OnTime Now()+TimeValue("00:00:01"), "DisplayMyTime"`, where "DisplayMyTime" is the name of the procedure that displays the elapsed time.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion I will try it and get back to you with the result as I am currently busy with other stuff.